# What is von Neumann's branching of possible worlds?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

In the Many Worlds Interpretation's wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation), it says, at the "Reception" part:

"*(...) On the other hand, the same derogatory qualification "many words" is often applied to MWI by its critics, who see it as a word game which obfuscates rather than clarifies by confounding the von Neumann branching of possible worlds with the Schrödinger parallelism of many worlds in superposition*"

I have not been able to find anything meaningful about "von Neumann branching of possible worlds". Do you know what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

The best account I've found online of von Neumann's analysis of quantum mechanics is [here](https://www.intechopen.com/books/selected-topics-in-applications-of-quantum-mechanics/the-measurement-problem-in-quantum-mechanics-revisited).  You can find an in-depth treatment in [von Neumann's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691028931).

Basically, von Neumann advocated the Many Worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics when there is no observer; and said however that from the perspective of an observer, the Copenhagen interpretation (wavefunction collapse) is appropriate.